# ifpackageloaded question

Tags: conditionals, options

why when i comment `\usepackage{geometry}` i get error?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}
 {                               % i the package was loaded 
    \newcommand*{\qw}{\itshape}  % this is enabled, else is not enabled.                                                                                               
 }{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\qw hallo
\end{document}
```

Comment: See section 96.3 in `source2e.pdf`.

Comment: The question has changed from its original form.

Comment: ...  and the edit makes the question quite confusing, as the code it contains works just fine.

Comment: Please don't change the question after it has been answered. This makes it very confusing for everybody. If you really need to, please add the corrected code below the original one, with some comment saying that you've taken it from the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX defines several conditional macros, with a syntax very different from the primitive

```
\if?<condition><true>\else<false>\fi
```

where `\if?` denotes any of the primitive conditionals. The conditionals defined by LaTeX have the form

```
\@ifsomething{<arg>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

or

```
\@ifsomething{<arg1>}{<arg2>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

Conditionals of the first kind are `\@ifundefined` and `\@ifpackageloaded`; among the second kind are `\@ifpackagelater` and `\@ifpackagewith`. The motivation for the distinction is that in the second kind we need something more to check a condition (the package name and an option name, for `\@ifpackagewith`).

The `<true>` and `<false>` code are executed respectively when the condition is satisfied or not. So

```
\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}
  {\newcommand\qw{\itshape}}
  {\newcommand\qw{\bfseries}}
```

is the answer. Either argument can be empty, of course.

You find an example of `\@ifpackageloaded` and some more information in Italian in [this book](http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf) (p. 78 for the main problem)

**Note** There is also `\@ifdefinable<control sequence>{<true>}` that has no "false" branch; it will execute the code `<true>` if the `<control sequence>` is undefined and raise an error otherwise (ignoring the `<true>` code).

Comment: I would to ask you if is better leave empty the argument (if I want to make nothing) or put into it the  command `\relax`. Also in the case of the `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@nameofboolean}}{}{}`  command, beacuse for examples, I have see into the `classicthesis.sty` many `\relax` as argument of that command. Thanks.

Comment: `classicthesis.sty` is *not* an example of good LaTeX programming, in my opinion. An empty argument is way better than filling it with `\relax`.

Comment: I have understand. Is possible made also somthing like: `\if@a5paper`?

Comment: @FormlessCloud That control sequence name is illegal; but there are examples in the `.sty` file of `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@a5paper}}{<true>}{<false>}`

Comment: Yes, I have seen those, but I wanted to make that condition without the ifthen package.

Comment: Sorry, I have however solved with the ifthen package :)

Comment: @FormlessCloud ClassicThesis loads it anyway, so why bother? And if you don't use ClassicThesis there's no "a5paper" boolean to begin with.

Comment: You are right, as ever ! I had thought that can be possible define that condition without that package and without ClassiThesis. So, since I think that is better don't load packages for nothing, I have ask you if is possible make it.

Comment: @FormlessCloud You have to say what you want to do in that case. With the standard classes, for instance `article`, you can say `\@ifclasswith{article}{a5paper}{<true>}{<false>}`

Answer (score 7):

The else part should go in the second argument:

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}
 {% if the package was loaded
  \newcommand*{\qw}{\itshape}%
 }
 {%else:
  \newcommand*{\qw}{\bfseries}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\qw hallo
\end{document}
```

Comment: and if i want to do nothing if is not loaded the package?

Comment: @FormlessCloud Leave the "false" argument empty.

Comment: @egreg, then `\qw` won't be defined. @FormlessCloud, what do you want `\qw` to be if you do not load geometry?

Comment: if I not load the package I would that nothing is do

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}
 {
    \newcommand*{\qw}{\itshape}  % this is enabled
 }{
    \newcommand*{\qw}{\bfseries} % this is enabled?
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\qw hallo
\end{document}
```

The `\@ifpackageloaded` takes two arguments: what to do if the package is loaded or not. Your `\if` doesn't really do anything.

**Edit: The question seems to have changed**

Now the problem is that if the package is not loaded, then the macro `\qw` does not get defined. Something like this might be what you want

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}
 {
    \newcommand*{\qw}{\itshape}  % this is enabled
 }{
    \newcommand*{\qw}{} % this is enabled?
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\qw hallo
\end{document}
```